# Al generar archivo xlsx con la clase phpspreadsheet, excel no lo puede leer porque se encuentra dañado

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

estoy generando un archivo xlsx utilizando la clase phpspreadsheet pero al generar el archivo, sale una ventana de error indicando que el formato o la extension no son validos. Estoy utilizando php 7.4 y Excel 365. Aqui el codigo:

```
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
    
    $documento = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
    $documento
        ->getProperties()
        ->setCreator("Aquí va el creador, como cadena")
        ->setLastModifiedBy('Parzibyte') // última vez modificado por
        ->setTitle('Mi primer documento creado con PhpSpreadSheet')
        ->setSubject('El asunto')
        ->setDescription('Este documento fue generado para parzibyte.me')
        ->setKeywords('etiquetas o palabras clave separadas por espacios')
        ->setCategory('La categoría');

    $nombreDelDocumento = "Mi primer archivo.xlsx";

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $nombreDelDocumento . '"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    
    $writer = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($documento, 'Xlsx');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

Este es el mensaje que me aparece cuando intento abrir el archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguien se sirve, el problema es que me hacia falta añadir otro header al final de todo:

```
header("Location: ".$nombreDelDocumento);
```